# Show that $\frac{\sin(xy)}{y}$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

How do I show that the following function is differentiable at $(0,0)$?
$$
\begin{cases}
  \dfrac{\sin(xy)}{y}, & \text{if }y \neq 0  \\
\\
  0, & \text{if }y = 0
\end{cases}
$$
I calculated the partial derivatives and

- $f(x) = \cos(xy)$ exists near $(0,0)$ and is continuous
- $f(y) = \dfrac{xy \cos(xy) - \sin(xy)}{y^2}$ exists, but how do I show that it is continuous?

Comment: If you know power series,  $g(u)=\frac{\sin(u)}{u}=\sum_{k\geq 0}(-1)^k\frac{u^{2k}}{(2k+1)!}$ (with $g(0)=1$) is $C^{\infty}$ on $\mathbb{R}$, now your function is $f(x,y)=xg(xy)$, and you are done.

Comment: Use the definition of the partial derivative to find $\partial _x f(0,0)$ and $\partial _y f(0,0)$. Then show they are continuous in $(0,0)$.

Comment: Are you sure that the condition is $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$? Is it maybe $y\neq 0$?

Answer (score 2):

As you defined it your function is not even continuous at $(0,0)$. Note that
$$\lim_{y\to0}{\sin(xy)\over y}=x\ .$$
I'm assuming this will be corrected. Then you can argue as follows: When $y\ne0$ you have
$${\sin(xy)\over y}=\int_0^x \cos(y t)\>dt\ ,$$
whereby the RHS is obviously $C^1$ in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$.